# Grayscale, monochrome, binary image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

In Matlab,

1. An 8-bit gray scale image has pixel values ranging from 0 to 255. The pixel depth may vary (16-bit, 32-bit, etc)
2. A binary image has pixel values, either 0 or 1 (logical)

My question is that, is monochrome image, a binary image or a gray scale image as per points 1 and 2. I  need clarification because I want to be 100 % sure about monochrome image.

(As per 'Digital Image Processing Using Matlab' by Gonzalez, Woods, Eddins, a monochrome image is a grayscale image. (Topic 3.2, pg no. 66))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monochrome and grayscale are mostly interchangeable. Monochrome data has only one color, but it's not always gray. For example digital x-ray data is monochrome because it has only intensity. The printout is typically grayscale but you could also use any other color. 
Sepia images are also monochrome, but strictly speaking not grayscale.